# Reference request: $\mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta_p) = \mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt[p-1]{-p})$

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $\mathbb{Q}_p$ be the $p$-adic numbers, for an odd prime $p$. Let $\mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta_p)$ be the extension obtained by adjoining the primitive $p^\mathrm{th}$ root of unity $\zeta_p$, and let $\mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt[p-1]{-p})$ be the extension obtained by adjoining a $(p-1)^\mathrm{st}$ root of $-p$. It is well-known (e.g. by following Example Sheet 3, Exercise 5 [here](https://tartarus.org/gareth/maths/notes/iii/Local_Fields_2011.pdf)) that $\mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta_p) = \mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt[p-1]{-p})$.

I am looking for a reference (ideally published) for this fact. I have tried looking in Serre's Local Fields and Neukirch's Algebraic Number Theory, as well as rooting around on the internet. I have found a few assertions of the fact, but no full proofs.

Comment: So you are looking for a reference which also includes a proof? Normally, it is enough to cite a paper which mentions a result, not necessarily with a proof. But I also avoid doing that since it is not helpful for the reader.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Ideally yes - I don't think citing something that just asserts the result gives any more credibility than just asserting the result myself. I suppose this fact is maybe famous enough that I can just say it's "well-known", but that always feels a bit disingenuous to me. I'm sure there are plenty of people in academia who don't remember this particular fact off the top of their head

Comment: I believe a proof is found in p-adic Numbers: An Introduction by Fernando Gouvea, although it might be spread out among the chapter and partially contained in an exercise solution in the back of the book.

Comment: Just on site, references are https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3760336/96384 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3432658/96384. User KCd calls this "famous" in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4824790/96384; user MAS calls the $p-1$-th root of $-p$ "Dwork's favorite choice" in a comment in one of the first two links.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both $x^{p-1} + p$ and the cyclotomic polynmial $\Phi_p(x) = (x^p-1)/(x-1)$ are irreducible over $\mathbf Q_p$ with degree $p-1$ and a root of either polynomial generates an extension of $\mathbf Q_p$ containing all the other roots of the polynomal, so it suffices to show the field generated over $\mathbf Q_p$ by a root of either polynomial contains at least one root of the other polynomial.

In Lemma 14.6 in the first edition of Washington's book "Introduction to Cyclotomic fields" (the chapter on the Kronecker-Weber theorem, and probably also Lemma 14.6 in the second edition), this is  proved by showing that when $\zeta_p$ is a nontrivial $p$th root of unity, $(\zeta_p - 1)^{p-1}/(-p)$ can be written as a $(p-1)$th power in $\mathbf Q_p(\zeta_p)$, say $a^{p-1}$. Then $-p = ((\zeta_p - 1)/a)^{p-1}$, so $\mathbf Q_p(\zeta_p)$ contains a root of $x^{p-1} + p$.  This is also in Gouvea's book "$p$-Adic Numbers: an Introduction": section 5.6 in the 1st edition and section 6.7 in the 3rd edition. It is not numbered as a theorem, but the section is only several pages long.  The argument there is similar to what Washington does, but with more details given.

In the proposition (not numbered) in section 2 of Chapter 7 of Robert's "A first course in $p$-adic analysis", writing $\pi$ for a root of $x^{p-1} + p$, it's shown how to build a nontrivial $p$th root of unity in $\mathbf Q_p(\pi)$ using an infinite series: $|\pi|_p = (1/p)^{1/(p-1)}$, the formal power series $f(x) := e^{x + x^p/p}$ has radius of convergence *bigger* than $|\pi|_p$, and $f(\pi)$ is a nontrivial $p$th root of unity.  This is surprising since naively you'd think $f(x)$ evaluated at a nonzero root of $x + x^p/p$ should have value $e^0 = 1$, but that's not what happens.

The reason our naive expectations are not met is that naively we think when $\pi + \pi^p/p = 0$ that $e^{\pi+\pi^p/p} = e^\pi{e}^{\pi^p/p} = e^\pi{e}^{-\pi} = e^0 = 1$, and the mistake there when $\pi \not= 0$ is in the 1st equation: $e^\pi$ and $e^{\pi^p/p}$ make no sense since $|\pi|_p = |\pi^p/p|_p = (1/p)^{1/(p-1)}$ and $e^x$ converges only when $|x|_p < (1/p)^{1/(p-1)}$. It is true (but not at all obvious) that $e^{x+x^p/p}$ as a formal power series converges at the $p$-adic roots of $x + x^p/p$, but the naive reason to think the value at those roots equals $1$ is wrong, and the value there really isn't $1$ (when $\pi \not= 0$).
In particular, $f(\pi)$ is *not* $e^{\pi + \pi^p/p}$. That is,
$e^{x+x^p/p}|_{x=\pi} \not= e^{\pi+\pi^p/p}$; evaluating a composition of formal power series $g(h(x))$ at a number $a$ is not actually defined to be $g(h(a))$; showing the evaluation really is $g(h(a))$ requires a proof, and sometimes the evaluation of $g(h(x))$ at $x = a$ simply isn't $g(h(a))$.

When we take $p$-th powers, $(e^{x+x^p/p})^p = e^{px + x^p}$ as formal power series, and when $\pi + \pi^p/p = 0$ we have $|p\pi|_p < (1/p)^{1/(p-1)}$ and $|\pi^p|_p = |-p\pi|_p < (1/p)^{1/(p-1)}$, so it *is* true that $e^{p\pi + \pi^p} = e^{p\pi}e^{\pi^p} = e^{p\pi}e^{-p\pi} = e^0 = 1$ even though it's not true that $\pi + \pi^p/p = 0 \Rightarrow e^{x+x^p/p}|_{x=\pi} = 1$.  So $\zeta_{\pi} := e^{x+x^p/p}|_{x=\pi}$ is a nontrivial $p$th root of unity when $\pi$ is a nonzero root of $x + x^p/p$.

The second approach is more technical than the first approach (both to show $f(x)$ has radius of to show $f(\pi)^p = 1$ with $f(\pi) \not= 1$), so I'd advise citing Washington's book.

Something the second approach reveals is a nice bijection between the roots of $\Phi_p(x)$ (nontrivial $p$th roots of unity) and the roots of $x^{p-1} + p$. The different roots of $\Phi_p(x)$ are at distance $(1/p)^{1/(p-1)}$ from each other, and the same is true for the different roots of $x^{p-1} + p$. When $\alpha$ runs over roots of $\Phi_p(x)$ and $\beta$ runs over roots of $x^{p-1} + p$, by asking for
$$
|(\alpha - 1) - \beta|_p < \left(\frac{1}{p}\right)^{1/(p-1)}
$$ we get a unique $\beta$ for each $\alpha$ and a unique $\alpha$ for each $\beta$. To each $\beta$,  the choice of $\alpha$ is $f(\beta) = e^{x+x^p/p}|_{x = \beta}$.  And this also works between roots of $x^p-1 = (x-1)\Phi_p(x)$ and $x^p/p + x = (x^{p-1} + p)x/p$, where $\alpha = 1$ is matched with $\beta = 0$.

Comment: The second approach looks fascinating. Is there a conceptual explanation / background for this? Are there other pairs of polynomials $(f,g)$ with a similar behaviour (the roots of $f$, when plugged into the formal power series $exp(f(x))$, give the roots of $g$)?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg  I updated some of what I wrote above to add more details.  When working with $e^x$, the only reasonable thing you might ask for is $e^{f(x)}|_{x=r}$ to be a ($p$-power) root of unity when $f(r) = 0$.  You don't expect $e^{f(r)}$ to converge, but maybe $e^{p^mf(r)}$ when $m$ is large enough. See Chapter VI in Fesenko and Vostokov's book on local fields for an analogue of this to express bases of units as values of certain series related to the Artin-Hasse series.